# Set view of another view is not properly set

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am taken a view and set the anchor. When i am adding in my view. They work onthe iPhone 5 but they show some margin in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *vwTop;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    top= [[NexaTopView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NexaTopView" bundle:nil];
    bottom=[[NexaBottomViewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NexaBottomViewViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.vwTop addSubview:top.view];
    [self.bottomView addSubview:bottom.view];

    [top.txtHeader setText:@"Notifications"];
    top.txtHeader.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}

   ![enter image description here][1]
```

but they show margin please help i m newer![enter image description here][2] in ios.

Comment: Are you using auto layout ? if yes than set frame in `Layoutsubview` method .i think its helpful to you.Thanks

Comment: @Ilesh i m using autolayout . please tell me how we use layout subview . i m new in iOS

Comment: set proper constrain and add subview in -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    
}

Comment: @Ilesh You're not keeping with MVC. It's better to create a subclass and implement `layoutSubviews` in view class instead of this solution, as it's not keeping up with patterns. The asker may swap the subview in loadView method.

Answer (score 0):

The Margin Problem can be of Auto layout. so refer it and do it.
for Auto layout....
http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Comment: i m using auto layout but they are not properly set

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a layout view and then add your view in layout view.Give layout view proper autolayout constrains.